# Format military time to 12 hours time in Hive

Tags: time, hive, hiveql, impala

I have time in military time format i.e. `18:10:45`

But I need it in standard time i.e. `06:10:45`
Also `AM` or `PM` indicator should be there.

So the final output will be `06:10:45 PM`

Comment: Sorry. It is impala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unix_timestamp()` converts timestamp with given format to unix timestamp and `from_unixtime()` converts unix timestamp to timestamp with the given format.

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('18:10:45', 'HH:mm:ss'),"hh:mm:ss a");
OK
06:10:45 PM
```